# Subselect statement to set integrity

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to set integrity to about 1000 tables which error out because of Pending State. I cannot go 1 by 1 as there are too many tables. The subquery returns the name of all the tables. This is the query that I use which is not working right now:

```
SET INTEGRITY FOR TABSCHEMA.TABNAME IMMEDIATE CHECKED IN 
( SELECT TABNAME 
  FROM SYSCAT.TABLES
  WHERE ( CONST_CHECKED LIKE '%N%' AND TABSCHEMA = 'FINANCE')
  WITH ur
)
```

Any idea?

Comment: Either do this in a script (any scripting language), or in a SQL-routine or SQL-anoymous-block. You need two separate steps. First step generates the SQL statements (one per table).  Second step executes each of those statements in turn.

Comment: yea im not really good with queries so I wouldn't know how to do what you described.. but thanks.. is there any solution I can run as the script above?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem of such a massive `SET INTEGRITY`s is, that if you have a parent-child pair in check-pending state, that you have to either include both tables into a single `SET INTEGRITY` command or run it on the parent table first, and on the child table with a subsequent command. You get an error, if you run `SET INTEGRITY` on a child table only, if the corresponding parent table is in the check pending state.

It's quite a non-trivial task to split all tables in check pending to distinct non-relative groups to run a single `SET INTEGRITY` on each such a group of tables.
This is why it's better to run a script like below:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
SET  SERVEROUTPUT ON@

DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.BAD_TABLES 
(
  TABSCHEMA VARCHAR (128) NOT NULL
, TABNAME VARCHAR (128) NOT NULL
) WITH REPLACE ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS NOT LOGGED@

BEGIN
  --DECLARE L_ITER INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE L_PROCESSED INT;
  DECLARE L_TABSCHEMA VARCHAR (128);
  DECLARE L_TABNAME VARCHAR (128);

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '23514'
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO SESSION.BAD_TABLES (TABSCHEMA, TABNAME) VALUES (L_TABSCHEMA, L_TABNAME);
  END;

  -- Ordinal tables processing
  L1: LOOP
    --SET L_ITER = L_ITER + 1;
    --CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Iteration ' || L_ITER);    
    SET L_PROCESSED = 0;
    FOR V AS C1 INSENSITIVE CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR 
      SELECT 
        'SET INTEGRITY FOR "' || T.TABSCHEMA || '"."' || T.TABNAME || '" IMMEDIATE CHECKED' AS CMD
      , T.TABSCHEMA
      , T.TABNAME
      FROM SYSCAT.TABLES T
      WHERE T.TYPE = 'T' AND T.STATUS = 'C'
      AND NOT EXISTS 
      (
      SELECT 1
      FROM SYSCAT.REFERENCES R
      JOIN SYSCAT.TABLES P ON P.TABSCHEMA = R.REFTABSCHEMA AND P.TABNAME = R.REFTABNAME 
      WHERE R.TABSCHEMA = T.TABSCHEMA AND R.TABNAME = T.TABNAME 
      AND P.STATUS = 'C'
      )
      AND NOT EXISTS
      (
      SELECT 1 FROM SESSION.BAD_TABLES B WHERE B.TABSCHEMA = T.TABSCHEMA AND B.TABNAME = T.TABNAME
      )
    DO
      SET (L_TABSCHEMA, L_TABNAME) = (V.TABSCHEMA, V.TABNAME);
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V.CMD;
      COMMIT;
      CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (V.CMD);
      SET L_PROCESSED = L_PROCESSED + 1;
    END FOR;
    CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Tables processed: ' || L_PROCESSED);
    IF L_PROCESSED = 0 THEN LEAVE L1; END IF;
  END LOOP L1;

  -- MQTs processing
  SET L_PROCESSED = 0;
  FOR V AS C1 INSENSITIVE CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR 
    SELECT 
      'SET INTEGRITY FOR "' || T.TABSCHEMA || '"."' || T.TABNAME || '" IMMEDIATE CHECKED' AS CMD
    , T.TABSCHEMA
    , T.TABNAME
    FROM SYSCAT.TABLES T
    WHERE T.TYPE = 'S' AND T.STATUS = 'C'
  DO
    SET (L_TABSCHEMA, L_TABNAME) = (V.TABSCHEMA, V.TABNAME);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V.CMD;
    COMMIT;
    CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (V.CMD);
    SET L_PROCESSED = L_PROCESSED + 1;
  END FOR;
  CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('MQTs processed: ' || L_PROCESSED);

END
@

SET  SERVEROUTPUT OFF@
```

Ordinal tables are processed iteratively. Each iteration processes a table, if it doesn't have its parent table in check pending at the moment.
MQTs are processed afterwards.
The table name is inserted into a session table, if `SET INTEGRITY` failed on it.

Comment: thanks so much i will try and get back to you